# output mysql table into comma separated file with python: syntax error

Tags: python, mysql, csv

I am trying to write a MySQL table into a csv table with proper comma separation. It works without formatting and the result is a tab separated file. I need however a comma separated file and I am getting a syntax error. Here is the code:

```
def export_csv(cxn, filename,filestamp,table, cols='*', where='1'):  
     cur = cxn.cursor()  
     cur.execute("select %s \ 
     into outfile '/tmp/%s-%s.csv' \  
     fields terminated by ',' optionally enclosed by '\"' \  
     escaped by '\\' \  
     lines terminated by '\n'  
     from %s \  
     where %s " \  
     % (cols, table, where, filename, filestamp))  
     cur.close()
```

It works in pure MySQL. I tried to add more escapes, to no avail.

Answer (score 2):

- Use triple quotes `'''` around a
  string that spans multiple lines, in
  this case around the select
  statement.

EDIT (there's more...)

- Don't add a backslash at end of line inside the triple-quoted string
- To pass a backslash to MySQL, escape with backslash `\\`, or add an r before opening quotes to mark raw string

Comment: def export_csv(cxn, filename, filestamp, table, cols='*', where='1'):
    
    cur = cxn.cursor()  
    cur.execute("""select %s into outfile '/tmp/%s-%s.csv'  
    fields terminated by ',' optionally enclosed by '"'   
    escaped by '\' lines terminated by '\n'   
    from %s where %s"""   
    % (cols, filename, filestamp, table, where))  
    cur.close()  
Thanks, this saved me from scrubbing the result with the csv module.